# How can I set std::map variable with gdb?

Tags: c++, stl, gdb

```
#include<map>
#include<iostream>
using std::map;
using std::cout;
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    map<int,int> kv({{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}});
    kv[1]=2;
    cout<<kv[1];
    return 0;
}
```

I start it from GDB and break at `kv[1]=2`. After `kv[1]=2` was executed, I want to set `kv[1]=3` in GDB. How can I do it?

Comment: _didn't work_ is not a helpful error description. Please [edit] in your code in the form of a [mcve], include any compiler / linker errors you received or behaviour that differed from your expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GDB set command to set the value

GDB Mode
modifying_command
: set [ variable ] expression

The following example shows how to deposit the value 5 into the data member of a C++ variable:
GDB Mode

```
(idb) print kv[1]

(idb) set variable {int}0x82040 = 5  //82040 is memory address
```

Comment: I'm trying to use set variable kv[1] = 5,but it tells that Could not find operator[].what's wrong with it?

Comment: Try using the memory   set {int}0x83040 = 5

Comment: @Davis-King Welcome